# Is there a framework that allows playing of video without any pre-installed drivers ? (H264)

Tags: java, video

I've been looking all over the web to find something that allows me to play H264/Mpeg4 videos in java. The videos are recorded on an android device and i would like to attach a java programm to my app that the user can move/copy to his/her harddrive and execute to play the video on the computer (bigger screen, mouse input etc).

I did find xuggler, vlcj, ffmpeg, gstreamer.
They all say that they require some driver etc to be installed on the computer. But i need something that runs in pure java and that can be put into the jar that i will put into my app or website dl.

It has to be as simple as that, user dl the jar and executes and is able to watch the video that is stores on the android device (i realize that it requires the user to have java installed, but thats the only thing i want to burden them with).

Links or tutorials are welcome.
(i work a lot with android but hardly with plain java, so the lack of multimedia abilities is kinda throwing me off balance)

Comment: I don't know what driver you refer, but obviously you need the video driver installed. maybe you are referring to the codecs?

Comment: the user shouldnt have to install anything. It should work on a plain vanilla windows with java directly after windows was installed. Hook up the android device, connect it via USB, transfer JAR file, execute and watch video on the PC.

Answer (score 0):

[JCodec](http://jcodec.org/index.html) is a recent project aimed at providing a pure-java implementation of video and audio decoders, worth a try.

Comment: project is with 0 documentation, hard to work into but its a possibility IF it really works